# Why does the font type change when I open a plot in a new window?

Tags: plot, rstudio, png, image-resizing, save-image

I'm coding in Rmarkdown and I prefered to change the font type of my plots using the following code:

```
windowsFonts(timesnewroman = windowsFont("Times New Roman"))
```

and in a ggplot plot adding:

```
 ... + theme(text = element_text(family = "timesnewroman"))
```

When I then open the plot using "Show in new window" button the font changes to the default font as it is in R plots in normal.
How can I avoid this change? Because when I open it in a new window I take a screenhot of the plot and use it in my report, so I don't wanted that the font type changed to the default. What can I do? :/

Comment: Taking screenshots is a bad way to save plots.  You should open a device (`png()` or `pdf()` can do this), do your plot, and then call `dev.off()` to save it.

Comment: The reason why I take screenshot is that when I open the plot in a new window I can adjust the size of the plot as I want

Comment: You can do that in the `png()` or `pdf()` function calls, too.

Comment: Okay, so I tried using the png() now but the plot just don't look as I wanted.. its very small.. I want it to be more wider since I have a 2x2 plot using `facet_grid` and `plot_grid`. I'm sorry I can not share my plot in here.

Comment: Don't share the true plot, just something that is the same size.  You specify the size you want using `png(..., width = ..., height = ...)`, so you can get any size you want.

Comment: @user2554330 I accept your comment as an answer/solution. Who of us should post it as an answer?

Comment: If you want to write it up as an answer, that would be great.  Include enough code so that future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on the answer given by @user2554330 the following worked for me:

```
library(cowplot) #use this library to use the plot_grid function

#saving the plot as an image with the prefered size
png(filename="my working directory/myplot.png", width = 850, height = 450)

plot_grid(plot1, plot2, labels = c("A", "B"), ncol = 2, nrow = 1, label_x = 0.45, label_y = 1.040, label_size = 13)

dev.off()
```

When using these codes the image with the prefered size is saved into my folder/working direction.